# What am I doing wrong in the implementation of this recursive function?

Tags: haskell, recursion

This is my code so far:

```
test n p
  |p > n  = 0
  |p == n = 1
  |otherwise = sum [test n-p q|q<-[1..p+1]]
```

This should implement a simple recursive function (accepting nonnegative integers)

[image]

However I do get an error message that I do not understand. (I was not able to copy it from the ghci console, so here I just typed it out) Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

```
Expected a constraint, but 'Int' has kind '*'
In the type signature for 'test': test :: Int -> Int => Int
```

Comment: Your type signature is wrong, but you didn't include it in the question. The type of `test` should be `Int -> Int -> Int`

Comment: Also, you need parentheses around `n-p`

Comment: I did not write any type signature so far, but thanks, it was the missing parenthesis! Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum [test n-p q|q<-[1..p+1]]
```

Function application has a very high precedence in Haskell. The above is parsed as:

```
sum [ (test n) - (p q) |q<-[1..p+1]]
```

Above `test` is used as a unary function returning a number, and `p` is also used as a unary function returning a number. This triggers a type error.

Also, note that the `=>` is wrong in the type signature:

```
test :: Int -> Int => Int
--                ^^^^
```

The above causes GHC to try parsing the left part `Int -> Int` as if it were a class constraint, but it is a type ("has kind `*`", in technical terms) so an error is reported.

Answer (score 1):

```
test n p
  |p > n  = 0
  |p == n = 1
  |otherwise = sum [test (n-p) q|q<-[1..p+1]]
```

I.e. parentheses around `(n-p)`